# Java Secret Word

Tags: java

I was given a assignment for my Intro to Computer Science class to make the user enter any word until they guess the secret word, once they get the secret word then the system will say "Stop!" So far I have the user trying once and I want the program to continue looping until the user enters the right word. I really need some help, this is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input;    //The users input

  // New Scanner for keyboard input
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Tell the user to guess the word
  System.out.print("Guess the secret word: ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();

  if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("college"))
  {
    System.out.print("Stop !");
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: The question is clear and well explained, so those downvotes are a bit hard. However, you should first learn the basics of programming before actually asking questions, as a lot of answers will be given to you by reading books/tutorials. As @AndyTurner said, you need a simple loop from which you will break when the user finds the secret word.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `while` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "";    //The users input

    // New Scanner for keyboard input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // The below code is run until the secret word is guessed.
    while (!"college".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
    {

      //Tell the user to guess the word
      System.out.print("Guess the secret word: ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();

   /* if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("college"))
      {
        System.out.print("Stop !");
      } This code is no longer necessary, as we have put the stop
        condition in the while loop declaration. */
    }

    // This only runs after the loop has finished
    System.out.println("Stop !");
  }
}
```

Comment: @MartinBG Would the same problem not arise if `input` was null and passed as a parameter?

Comment: `Would the same problem not arise if input was null and passed as a parameter?` - No, as [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) method just returns `false` on invokation with `null` argument.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a do-while loop.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input;    //The users input
        boolean hasGuessedCorrectly = false;

        // New Scanner for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Tell the user to guess the word
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Guess the secret word: ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("college"))
            {
                hasGuessedCorrectly = true;
                System.out.print("Stop !");
            }
        } while (!hasGuessedCorrectly);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop could be used for this task:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static final String SECRET_WORD = "college";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Guess the secret word: ");
        } while (!SECRET_WORD.equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Stop!");
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B1vLcS6uH)